# One at a time C++ win 32

Tags: win32gui

My question is : In win32 I send messages to the textbox with (for example, a sample of my code)

```
SendMessage(TextBox,EM_SETSEL,-1,-1); //no difference between passing 0 or -1
SendMessage(TextBox,EM_REPLACESEL,TRUE,(LPARAM)buf2);
//SendDlgItemMessage(TextBox, IDC_PLAYERLIST,  LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
//hwnd.refresh();
SetWindowText( GetDlgItem( TextBox, IDC_EDIT ), "" );
```

But it doesnt clear the textbox.

So how do i clear the textbox so i can output another question that i would like to ask the user?

For knowledge, I develop a software in which people are asked different things , therefore i need step by step to appear the questions not all at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `TextBox` is the HWND of your actual edit control, and not its parent dialog, than replace

```
SetWindowText( GetDlgItem( TextBox, IDC_EDIT ), "" );
```

With

```
SetWindowText( TextBox, "" );
```

Comment: @XLexusX The point Remy is making is that the `GetDlgItem` function takes a dialog box and looks inside it for a control on it. But `TextBox` is already the control. Passing it to a function that expects a dialog box doesn't result in anything useful. It certainly won't find the text box control (since there is no control inside your TextBox control.)

Comment: I've tried your option (Remy) but it skips the questions and prints out only the last question.How to do it in order to go through the questions one by one?

Comment: It sounds like you are looping through your questions without pausing in between them. You are going to have to show more of your code if you want help with that logic. Please post a new question for that. This question (how to clear an edit control?) has been answered as asked.